# On a decomposition of $2\times2$ integer matrix

Tags: nt.number-theory, matrices

Given an integer matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ with determinant $det$ and two positive integers $m,n:m+n=det$, when is it possible to write it sum of two integer matrices $\begin{bmatrix}a_1&b_1\\c_1&d_1\end{bmatrix}$ with determinant $m$ and $\begin{bmatrix}a_2&b_2\\c_2&d_2\end{bmatrix}$ with determinant $n$ such that $$a_2 d_1 + a_1 d_2 - b_2 c_1 - b_1 c_2=0$$ holds?

Comment: Yes, by taking one of the matrices to be the zero matrix, but you probably wanted to exclude this case.

Comment: Wanted positive decomposition of determinants.

Comment: Even if you want $m$ and $n$ to be strictly positive, can't you just pick one of the matrices to be diagonal and the other to be anti-diagonal? E.g., pick $a_1 = m$, $d_1 = 1$, $b_2 = -n$, $c_2 = 1$, and the rest equal to $0$?

Comment: I do not see $a_1+a_2=a$, etc.

Comment: The (22) entry of your original matrix and the determinant are both denoted by $d$. Is that intentional? Are these meant to be the same?

Comment: The extra condition is just the difference $d-m-n$, so it is certainly zero. So your question reads as `can we decompose the matrix of determinant $d$ into a sum of matrices with determinants $m$ and $n$?

Comment: Just a comment that might be helpful: since the matrices are $2 \times 2$, we have the equality $\det(A+B)=\det A+\det B+\det A\,\cdot \mathrm{Tr}(A^{-1}B)$ when $A$ is invertible. In particular, if you want $\det(A+B) = \det(A) + \det(B)$, then you need $\mathrm{Tr}(A^{-1}B) = 0$.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt corrected.

Comment: @TomDeMedts $Tr(A^{-1}B)=Tr(B^{-1}A)=0$?